# Visual Studio for mac 2017+PHP Синтаксис

Tags: php, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, extension

Где найти и как установить PHP Синтаксис - Extensions для Visual Studio for Mac 2017

Comment: https://www.devsense.com/ оно?

Comment: пробывал ставить, но когда выбираешь установить через файл в выборе в директории нету и при выборе с любого файла - он просто не ставится(ничего не происходит) в списке по поиску его нету.
p.s такая же проблема с любым другим Extensions.

Comment: Может проблема в студии?

Comment: Сейчас попробую переустановить

Comment: не помогло, вопрос актуален.

Answer (score 0):

Пока в Extensions нету фильтрации VS2017 for mac и они просто не совместимы. 

тех. ответил
 
- yes i understand that at present it don't have a filter for mac, may be in days to come it may be added.

Так-же по интеграции TFS(кому нужно):
 
-at present it is not integrated.(TFS)
 -VS 2017 for mac is very new and may be in days to come they may add all the features similar to one on VS 2017 windows.